# Java Code: Sharepoint Graph API CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-api

Sharepoint Graph API to generate an Access token

URL to generate access token `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/token`
URL to download a file from sharepoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drive/root:/{file-path}`

When I access the above two URLs in Postman, it works fine.

I have written a code in Java Spring Boot to automate them.
Generating access token works fine I can use the generated token in postman to download a file also works fine.

But When I use the generated token in Java spring boot it does gives 401 Unauthorized and the result is `{"error":{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationToken","message":"CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217","innerError":{"date":"2021-10-22T06:03:42","request-id":"857c8f56-a22c-4f63-b0be-5cd66b0bf790","client-request-id":"857c8f56-a22c-4f63-b0be-5cd66b0bf790"}}}`, but with the same access token in post man it works fine.

---

To Generate Access Token

```
 @FeignClient(url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com", name = "sharepoint", configuration = CoreFeignConfiguration.class)
    public interface SharepointAccessTokenFeignClient {
        @RequestMapping(value = "/{tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/token", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
        @Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        Map<String, Object> generateAccessToken(@PathVariable("tenant-id") String tenantId,
                                                Map<String, ?> formParams);
    }
```

To Download File

```
@FeignClient(url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites", name = "sharepoint-graph")
public interface SharepointGraphFeignClient {

    @GetMapping(value = "/{site-id}/drive/root:/{file-path}")
    Map<String, Object> getDownloadURL(@PathVariable("site-id") String siteId,
                                       @PathVariable("file-path") String filePath,
                                       @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization", required = true) String token);
}
```

Comment: Could you share your code? How do you create authorization header?

Comment: Updated with the code

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer.
The OAuth 2.0 SAML bearer assertion flow allows you to request an OAuth access token using a SAML assertion when a client needs to use an existing trust relationship. The signature applied to the SAML assertion provides authentication of the authorized app. A SAML assertion is an XML security token issued by an identity provider and consumed by a service provider. The service provider relies on its content to identify the assertion’s subject for security-related purposes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-saml-bearer-assertion

Need to set up FS and Enabling Single Sign-On to Office 365

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/canitpro/step-by-step-setting-up-ad-fs-and-enabling-single-sign-on-to-office-365